# Global variable won't save in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, global-variables

How do I update a global variable's value after setting it equal to a return valued in a function?

When I call the global variable later, I get the the value I initially set it to, and not the fun generated by the function.

How do I update my global variable to reflect the changed value from the function?

My code:

```
 var itemImages10 = [Int: UIImage]()
 var myImages: [UIImage] = []


    func viewDidLoad() {
    var query = PFQuery(className: "Items")
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            let imageObjects = objects as! [PFObject]
            for (index, object) in enumerate(imageObjects) {

                if let thumbnail1 = object["image1"] as? PFFile {

                    thumbnail1.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock{(imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                        if error == nil {
                            if let image = UIImage(data: imageData!) {
                                self.itemImages10[index] = image
                                myImages = itemImages10.values.array

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
}


 println(myImages)  // returns empty array
```

Comment: can you post your code ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, I suggest you take a look at the how to ask a good question page: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you're asking to print the dictionary while it's still being populated in a different thread. When you use findObjectsInBackground the code inside of the closure may execute in a different thread.

// Update

You're nesting two background thread methods and then trying to access a variable that you set inside of the inner most one - The statements you execute in a function are executed in order, when a closure is used the code inside of it may be executed AFTER other statements in the function that called it. println(myImages) is being called BEFORE the code in the closures has completed.

//Update 2 - added code showing print statement inside of closure

```
 var itemImages10 = [Int: UIImage]()
 var myImages: [UIImage] = []


func viewDidLoad() {
var query = PFQuery(className: "Items")
query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        let imageObjects = objects as! [PFObject]
        for (index, object) in enumerate(imageObjects) {

            if let thumbnail1 = object["image1"] as? PFFile {

                thumbnail1.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock{(imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {
                        if let image = UIImage(data: imageData!) {
                            self.itemImages10[index] = image
                            myImages = itemImages10.values.array
                            println(myImages) // Here, inside the closure

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: How can I update my global variable then? Retrieve from the thread it executes in?

Comment: It is being updated, just move your print function inside of the closure if you want to see when it's updated.

Comment: Right but when I try to set the contents of itemImages to another value, it returns empty. Code updated. I'm setting myImages to it because I need to use myImages in later functions.

Comment: How can I access the value of the variable once the code in the closure has completed?

Comment: You can do it inside the closure that adds items to the dictionary, You can test it by adding the print statement to the closure itself.

Comment: I just updated the code with what I think you meant? But when I print I still get an empty array.

Comment: added code to my answer, putting the print inside the closure

Comment: Yes but I'm saying that I need myImages for more functions later...with the value retrieve from viewDidLoad. So the myImages variable needs to fill with the returned images in an array (which it does, as shown by the println) but when I try to use myImages in a later function, I get an empty array (default value)

Comment: So call that function from within the closure

Comment: Well that did it... thanks for sticking in there with me!